# Why does KDE not show up following install kubuntu-desktop?

Tags: installation, kde

I installed KDE with `apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` as suggested. The packages were downloaded and installed.  However, following reboot it went straight to the old Ubuntu Unity.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install this along side the original Ubuntu desktop?

If so log out and choose KDE from the selection box.

This image might help:

[image]

After selecting it it will be the default option.